# dynamic sql from the below sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Could you please help me create a dynamic sql from the below sql code.

```
select * 
  from (SELECT U.ODF_PARENT_ID PROJECT_ID, 
               U.ID UNIT_ID, 
               COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID, 
               SUM(NVL(SLICE,0)) SLICE, 
               TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'MON YY') Month_label
          FROM ODF_SL_5019059, 
               ODF_CA_PPD_UNIT_FORECAST UF,
               ODF_CA_PPD_UNIT U, 
               NBI_DIM_OBS COUNTRY_OBS
         WHERE SLICE_REQUEST_ID=5005021
           AND PRJ_OBJECT_ID = UF.ID
           AND UF.ODF_PARENT_ID=U.ID
           AND U.ODF_PARENT_ID = 5131001
           AND  UF.PPD_COUNTRY=COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID
         --AND TRUNC(SLICE_DATE,'MONTH') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH')
           AND TRUNC(SLICE_DATE,'YEAR') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')
         GROUP BY U.ODF_PARENT_ID, 
                  U.ID, 
                  COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID, 
                  TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'MON YY')
       ) main
  pivot (sum(SLICE) 
          for MONTH_LABEL IN ('Jan 00' , 'Feb 00', 'Apr 18'))
```

I am not able to convert it.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: And what's the dynamic part? Different table(s), different column(s)? Which?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what is supposed to be dynamic and I'm not too sure how it will be used. However, below is one way to build a dynamic SQL statement.

```
declare
  l_query            VARCHAR2(4000);
  L_SLICE_REQUEST_ID NUMBER;
  L_ODF_PARENT_ID    NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT ODF_PARENT_ID
  INTO   L_ODF_PARENT_ID
  FROM   TABLE;
  SELECT SLICE_REQUEST_ID 
  INTO   L_SLICE_REQUEST_ID 
  FROM   TABLE;

  l_query := q'#
    select * 
    from (SELECT U.ODF_PARENT_ID PROJECT_ID, 
                 U.ID UNIT_ID, 
                 COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID, 
                 SUM(NVL(SLICE,0)) SLICE, 
                 TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'MON YY') Month_label
          FROM   ODF_SL_5019059, 
                 ODF_CA_PPD_UNIT_FORECAST UF,
                 ODF_CA_PPD_UNIT U, 
                 NBI_DIM_OBS COUNTRY_OBS
          WHERE  SLICE_REQUEST_ID=[[L_SLICE_REQUEST_ID]]
          AND    PRJ_OBJECT_ID = UF.ID
          AND    UF.ODF_PARENT_ID=U.ID
          AND    U.ODF_PARENT_ID = [[L_ODF_PARENT_ID]]
          AND    UF.PPD_COUNTRY=COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID
          AND    TRUNC(SLICE_DATE,'YEAR') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')
          GROUP BY U.ODF_PARENT_ID, 
                   U.ID, 
                   COUNTRY_OBS.OBS_UNIT_ID, 
                   TO_CHAR(SLICE_DATE,'MON YY')
       ) main
    pivot (sum(SLICE) 
      for MONTH_LABEL IN ('Jan 00' , 'Feb 00', 'Apr 18'));
  #';
  l_query  := REPLACE(l_query, '[[L_SLICE_REQUEST_ID]]', L_SLICE_REQUEST_ID);
  l_query  := REPLACE(l_query, '[[L_ODF_PARENT_ID]]', L_ODF_PARENT_ID);

  <<Execute the l_query variable>>
END;
```